# Disabling secure button type in code behind file

Tags: asp.net

I have a button type of securebutton. I am trying to disable the button in my code behind file but the Enabled=false property is not applying to my button. Here is my code:

```
 <cc1:SecureButton ID="sbtnPromote" runat="server" Text="Promote" IsRegExAction="True"
                    CssClass="button" OnClick="sbtnPromote_Click" meta:resourcekey="sbtnPromoteResource1"/>

sbtnPromote.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Are you executing that statement (sbtnPromote.Enables = false) within Page_Load() ?

Comment: yes. I am executing this on Page_load based on some condition

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using a User Control for secure button.

Before, the

sbtnPromote.Enabled = false; statement, add the below statement.

Button sbtnPromote= ((Button)FindControl("sbtnPromote"));

Inside FindControl Method, Prepend your User control's Tag Name with $.
For example, if the User Control's tag Name is "Web", then you have to make the parameter "sbtnPromote" as "Web$sbtnPromote"